# Poetry - [AttributeError] 'bool' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, dependencies, package, python-poetry

I am using poetry as a dependency manager for python, and when I'm trying to install the dependencies using poetry:

```sh
poetry install
```

I get this error:

```
$ poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file

[AttributeError]
'bool' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Any ideas on what possibly can cause this error on happening because It doesn't let the dependencies install...

Example of pyproject.toml

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "orex"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
fastapi = ">=0.52.0"
SQLAlchemy = ">=1.3.12"
pydantic = {extras = ["email"], version = "^1.3"}
click = "^7.0"
alembic = "^1.3.2"
uvicorn = "^0.11.1"
passlib = "^1.7.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
pydantic = {extras = ["email"], version = "^1.3"}
```

to

```
pydantic = "{extras = ['email'], version = '^1.3'}"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).